# Glassfish 3.1, JAXB counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions, no detail

Tags: java, jaxb, glassfish-3

I have the following method:

```
public String getXML() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(questionSet.getClass());
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE); // Include indentation and linefeeds
    m.marshal(questionSet, writer);

    return writer.toString();
}
```

It throws "9 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions" on the JAXBContext instantiation line which is nicely recorded to my Glassfish 3.1 log file.  But I see no details as to what those counts are.  Does anyone know why I might not be getting the details?  Is there a configuration change I need to make?

Thanks!

Comment: How does you `questionSet` class look ?

Comment: What happens when you create the `JAXBContext` in a standalone application outside of GlassFish?

Comment: Blaise Doughan - I would not know how to create the context outside of Glassfish.  Something has to host it right?  More importantly my issue is really with Glassfish and the logs which is what I am trying to fix so I can figure out how to fix the other stuff, right?     Santosh - I could include the class, but it is really a collection of classes so it is BIG!  Also, I am not really looking to debug the classes here so much as figure out why nothing is showing up in the log.  Can that be effected by the classes themselves?

Comment: If it is your JAXB impl throwing the exceptions then you can get a more detailed trace from a standalone program.  No host is required, a JAXB impl is included in Jaca SE 6:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to determine why the details did not show up in the log.  However, the details do appear in the caught error message so I have added a break point there rather than keep fighting with the log.

Thank you to everyone who thought about it!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `printStackTrace()` on the exception.

The `IllegalAnnotationsException` contains a list of `IllegalAnnotationException` objects that contain information about the problematic annotations.  Unfortunately, this list is not appended to the exception message, nor does it fit in the stack trace directly, so you might not see them through normal logging.  But `IllegalAnnotationsException` does overload `toString()` to include this information.  And `printStackTrace()` uses `toString()` in its implementation.